# Calling a ruby action/method without redirecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, redis

I have a action called `new` in ConversationsController. I also have a view for it, `new.html.erb`, which has the following:

```
<%= button_to "New", action: "save_it" %>
```

In ConversationsController I have one more action, `save_it`, which is doing some action on a Redis database.

Everything here is working fine. When I click on button, the `save_it` action is running and the Redis database action is also happening successfully.

The problem is I am being redirected to `save_it.html.erb`. Is there any way I can call `save_it` such as to only perform the database commands without redirecting anywhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... I put my `save_it` action in

> /app/helpers/conversations_**helper.rb**

instead of

> /app/controllers/**conversations_controller.rb**

so now the `save_it` is a normal method in the conversations_helper.rb. This can be invoked from the new.html.erb by creating a normal HTML button

```
<input type="button" onclick=" <%= save_it -%> "  value="save" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call it with remote:true condition to make it an ajax call. It will try to load the save_it.js.erb without reloading the page.

```
<%= button_to "New", action: "save_it", remote: true %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve from your controller action:

```
def save_it
  # do stuff
  render nothing: true
end
```

I think, this do the trick.